# Android SkypeOut Replicate Functionality

Tags: android, sms, messaging

I've just installed Skype on my Android phone and I've noticed that when I am to make a call, using either Keypad or choosing a contact, I get a "Complete action using" option list with the "Keypad" and "SkypeOut" options in it.

I can understand that Skype's developers managed to some how "intercept" my intention to make a call and gave me the options mentioned above.

My question is how can I achieve the same behaviour in my application for both making an outgoing call and sending an outgoing sms.

My real intention is to make an option list with "Messaging" and "MyApplication" options to be shown whenever the user tapps the button "Send" in the stock messaging application.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime an Intent is fired which could be handled by multiple apps (more precisely, by multiple activities), the OS will ask the user to choose, it's not specific to calls or Skype. A common example is sharing: for example, if you click "Share" in the gallery, you will get a list of installed apps that can be used as a sharing tool: GMail, Facebook, Twitter, Buzz etc. See the Dev Guide article "[Intents and Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html)" for more details.